# oracle cloud instance stopped everytime powershell closed

Tags: spring, powershell, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

i was following this tutorial

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/spring-on-ol/01oci-ol-spring-summary.htm

and it works perfectly, but everytime i closed my windows powershell, the server stopped, but the status is already running in my oracle cloud dashboard, is there anyway to make spring boot keep running even when the powershell is closed ?

i have tried looking for any running option on the oracle cloud dashboard, but i have no luck finding it

Answer (score 1):

I assume you logged into compute instance via SSH using Powershell. Normally the process started on SSH session (PowerShell) would get killed if your logged-in SSH session ends. To keep your application running, please run your application in the background as below.

```
nohup java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar &
```

Ref: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html